# How to find the next occurrence of a string in a file starting from $x line number.

Tags: bash

In the following example, I have a variable $line set to "14" which relates to the 14th line of the file which is "four".

I need to find a way in BASH to start at whichever line number is set in ($line) (14) and find the line number of the next occurrence of a string (foo) in the same file. In this case , the result would be line 16.

```
one
foo
bar
foo
two
foo
three
foo
foo
bar
foo
foo
foo
four
bar
foo
bar
five
foo
six
foo
foo
bar
foo

$line = "14"
$search = "foo"
```

Comment: Do you need this to be in PURE bash, or are you open to using other tools that might be available in your shell? What have you tried? Include some code, and we can help you fix it. Is there any significance to the content of line number `$line`, or is it merely a starting point for the search for `$search`? You've got good sample data and a reasonably stated problem, now you just need to include your attempt to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Lots of ways to do this. But if you want to do it in bash alone (i.e. no awk, perl, etc), here's one way:

```
$ mapfile -t -O 1 a < ttt
$ for ((i=$line; i<=${#a[@]}; i++)); do [[ "${a[$i]}" = "$string" ]] && echo "$i" && break; done
```

The `mapfile` command sucks your file into an array (in a way that performs better than `read` in a loop), and the `-O 1` causes it to start numbering array indices at 1 instead of 0. The for loop steps through the array, starting at `$line`, with a `[[` that compares the current array value with `$string`.

I'd still love to see what solution *you* came up with, and help you understand why it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try awk:

```
line=14
search=foo
awk '(NR > n && $0 == s){ print NR; exit }' n=$line s="$search" file
```

Output:

```
16
```

You can assign the result to a variable this way:

```
declare -i var=$(awk '(NR > n && $0 == s){ print NR; exit }' n=$line s="$search" file)
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed` one-liner -

Using your data, naming it "infile", I get

```
$: line=14 search=foo sed -n $line,\${/$search/\{=\;q}} infile
16
```

This sets variables for the env before executing `sed`, and tells it not to output anything unasked with `-n`.

the command `$line,\${/$search/\{=\;q}}` evaluates to `14,${/foo/{=;q}}`

That means "from line 14 to the end, find the next line that has "foo" in it, and then

> print the line number (`=`) and
>
> quit (`q`) without processing the rest of the file.

Comment: (Hi, Adrian!) :D